# SSR project with VUE 3, express and usevue/head

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering

So I have a project on vue 3, in with was requested to add metadata(og, and twitter), so has been a long week, due I never had to work with something like that before, and it seems there are only 2 options available as I can see, so I have chose to work with usevue/head plugin, however the SSR part was not clear in the documentation, assuming that you already know. So after a long research, testing, and watching tutorials, I found how to, the component rendering to head was the easy part and is done(in my main project not in this repository, because my project I still don't have the ssr part and it's what I'm trying to figure out).

However for the SSR I created a empty project([check repository here](https://github.com/maria-arce/SSR-Test/tree/master)) where I just want to run the server together   with the plugin example code from the documentation, however now I'm facing 2 issues:

- For some reason the css coming from the components is not being "compile" by the server.
- More important, when importing the usevue/head plugin into the project I got an error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: useHead is not defined"

I suppose is because now I have 2 "main" js files, one for the server, and one for the client side, so I'm guessing that I need to import somehow the plugin to the main.server one as well, which currently looks like that:

```
import App from './App.vue'

export default App;
```

While my client side one looks like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createHead } from '@vueuse/head'

const head = createHead();

createApp(App).use(head).mount('#app');
```

If I am guessing correctly, the question is, how do you include in general a third party plugin in a server side file, not to mention the router?

Thank you in advance for your help. Also if you can recommend something else, also is very welcome.

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at https://nuxtjs.org/
They've just released their Vue 3 version as a Beta on Tuesday: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: Hello @Thomas I know what you mean, however, lets says this is basically end project and missing the meta part, which was not expecting to be include, I am afraid to go "to experimental" because the deadline, and not sure how easy could be to migrate, did you play with this version already?

Comment: I can understand, and no my projects didn't leave me time to test it out yet, and I only made one small side project with Nuxt2 and the composition API plugin for Vue2.